# Serving two sites on the same domain on different ports

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a service that serves http requests to http://localhost:9500 on a linux server. The same linux server is already configured to serve a public website with domain https://example.com on port 443 via nginx. Can I configure nginx to also serve the localhost service at https://example.com:9500?

My current nginx config

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;
    server_tokens off;
    root /home/app/example.com/public;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/1722357/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/1722357/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256
-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA38
4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: `location /service/ { proxy_pass http://localhost:9500/ }` to access the service at https://example.com/service/ assuming the existing website doesn’t use that path already. There’s more nuance than that if the “service” sends redirects and needs to be aware of the reverse proxy.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JakeHolzinger. Your pointers were really helpful. I had to use 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost to get it working, though. Can you please post your tip as an answer so I can mark the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind to the same port which is already being used. You can reverse-proxy to the upstream server at some arbitrary path of your choosing. You'll have to pick a path that isn't already used for serving the existing server content.

Assuming the path `/service` isn't already being used you can use the `location` directive to proxy to the upstream server as follows:

```
location /service/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9500/;
}
```

Then you will be able to access the service at: https://example.com/service/

This will strip off the `/service/` part of the path before passing it to the upstream service. Depending on what the service does you may have to send in additional headers for things to work correctly. For instance, redirects to another location may not work because the reverse proxy isn't passing the correct host (and protocol - see `X-Forwarded-Proto`) information down to the service.

See this introductory guide for more information:
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/